# Number of digits in the number $N=(1.6 \times 10^{32})!$

Tags: factoring, factorial

I am trying to find the number of digits in 
$$N=(1.6 \times 10^{32})!$$ where ! denotes Factorial. I have no idea how to proceed, please help me.

Comment: Hint: $\log_{10}N=\frac1{\ln(10)}\sum_{i=1}^{1.6\times10^{32}}\ln(i)$, and the sum can be approximated by an integral.

Answer (score 6):

I can give an approximate answer. For large numbers (and $10^{32}$ certainly qualifies), Stirling's approximation holds:
$$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.$$
Thus, the number of digits of large factorials is approximately
$$\text{dig}(n!)\approx\log_{10}(n!)\approx\frac 12\log_{10}(2\pi n)+n\log_{10}(n/e).$$
In the case that $n=1.6\times 10^{32}$, I get $5.08317\times 10^{33}$.

Comment: Even $(n/e)^n$ is accurate enough.

Comment: True. The leading term is minuscule for such large numbers.